# Center Container for JQuery Packery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, packery

I use [JQuery Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) which works fine.

The question that occurs to me is how can I center the item container on my page?

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item w2">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

I tried css:

```
#container {
 marin: 0 auto;
}
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Have a look a this issue: https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/8 TL:DR code here: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/xEzKo

Comment: can you please formulate an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeSandro already has an example of a centered packery layout.

The example is [here](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/xEzKo).

Basically it is just centered via CSS. I'm copying the code here too:

HTML:

```
<h1>Packery - centered</h1>
<div class="packery js-packery" data-packery-options='{ "gutter": ".gutter-sizer", "itemSelector": ".item", "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer" }'>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="item w2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item w2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.packery {
  background: #FDD;
  background: hsla(45, 100%, 40%, 0.2);
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* clearfix */
.packery:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.gutter-sizer {
  width: 2%;
}

.grid-sizer {
  width: 18.4%;
}

.item {
  width: 18.4%;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  background: #C09;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
}

.item.w2 { width: 38.8%; background: #9C0; }
.item.h2 { height: 120px; background: #0C9; }
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this.. this does what you need..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dbpzu

Comment: I need to center the elements inside the packery class. I also need a corner stamp.